# Any Garbage value in STL stack in c++?

Tags: c++, stack

```
stack<int> s;
while(!s.empty()) s.pop;
```

I saw this in a book before using a STL stack. this means if the stack holds any value this will be popped out. but when I used a stack.I saw it don't hold any value after declaration. Is there any possibility to hold any garbage value after declaration of STL stack?

Comment: If your book really shows this exact code, burn it, scatter its ashes to the wind, and get a better book.

Comment: Stacks start off empty, if that's your question

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik why?

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov Because it's nonsense. For one thing, a stack is empty right after declaration, so running a loop popping off non-existent elements is pointless. For another, parens after `pop` are missing - it's not even a valid syntax.

Comment: A default-constructed `std::stack` is empty. You can however use constructor arguments to provide initial items.

Comment: Fyi, you can clear a `std::stack` without a loop like this: `std::stack<int>().swap(s);` (create a *temporary* empty stack and *swap* its contents with the full stack).

Answer (score -2):

To simply answer your question, basically once you declare a stack it is not initialized with garbage values.
(It is good practice to initialize stuff in general though)

Comment: When you create a stack it does not contain garbage values. By default it is empty.

Comment: In C++, nothing is "automatically initialized with garbage values". Things are either initialized or uninitialized. `std::stack` is default initialized to be empty. Emptiness is emptiness. No garbage values.

Comment: @NickyC _nothing_ is such a strong word... "In C++, nothing is "automatically initialized with garbage values"." POD (plain old data) variables can hold garbage values if not initialized properly (and depending on storage class).

Comment: @NickyC "leaving it uninitialized" was exactly what I meant with "not initialized properly" Sorry, my poor wording... ;-)